# How to build PrototypeJS from source?

Tags: build, rake, prototypejs, sprockets

I cloned prototype.js repository, but when i trying to build, i get the error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Sprockets::Secretary
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was also having this problem.

Try using a different version of sprockets.

```
gem uninstall sprockets, gem install sprockets --version 1.0.2
```

1.0.2 was the version that worked for me.

Comment: This problem solved when i install ruby-1.8.7. Sprockets use ruby 1.8.7.